# Tracker for cellular network access (call detail records and data usage)

Tags: gratis, android

I am looking for free (as in beer, [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) preferred) applications that can track and visualize cellular network access and usage. The application should track information similar to [call detail records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_detail_record) and their pendants for SMS and data usage. A visualization could be e.g. usage per day or a location history inferred from access points, but also other. Here is what I found so far:

- [CallTrack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.calltrack&hl=en)
- [Cell Tracker (1)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gcm_celltracker)
- [Cell Tracker (2)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appbasic.celltracker)
- [Mobile Location Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crazyapps.mobilelocationtracker)

Background: I am planning to build such an app based on [this library](https://github.com/datagiraffe/cellservice) and I want to know, what's already out there.

Comment: Not a direct recommendation, as it's too long ago I've used any of those. But you might find something fitting in my app list on [Statistics for calls, messages, data](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_statistics). As for FOSS, especially watch out for the F-Droid app icons :)